# Where to add license information for local Qlik Core instance

Tags: qliksense

I have the docker qlik core image installed and running on my local machine. The trial period has expired and I have a license and control number. How do I enable qlik core with the license so that I can keep using it. I couldn't find anything that clearly explains it in the documentation. Any help and pointing in the right direction would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Just to mention that I haven't use license myself. I keep re-creating the image every 30 days (which is valid use)

The idea is that you are not using the license from within Core. You need to have a "companion" License service/container. Once you have this container up and running then you configure Core to connect to it

You can find more information the licensing on the official page [core.qlik.com](https://core.qlik.com/services/licenses/)

The `docker-compose.yml` below is an example how to start both containers. The repo with the script is [core-using-licenses](https://github.com/qlik-oss/core-using-licenses)

```
version: "3.0"

services:

  qix-engine:
    image: qlikcore/engine:12.429.0
    command: -S AcceptEULA=${ACCEPT_EULA} -S LicenseServiceUrl=http://licenses:9200 -S TrafficLogVerbosity=5 -S SystemLogVerbosity=5
    ports:
      - 19076:9076
      - 9090:9090
    labels:
      qix-engine: ""

  licenses:
    image: qlikcore/licenses:1.37.0
    environment:
      - LICENSES_SERIAL_NBR
      - LICENSES_CONTROL_NBR
      - LICENSES_LOG_LEVEL=debug
    ports:
      - 9200:9200
```